# Removing text from HTML buttons on all browsers?

Tags: html, css, button

We have buttons of many sizes and colors that use background images. There is a label on the background image itself, but we need to keep the button's text in the HTML for usability/accessibility. How do I make the text disappear in all browsers?

Modern browsers are easy, I just used -

```
color: transparent;
```

It's Internet Explorer 7 that I can't get to comply. I've tried these CSS properties, and none of them can remove the text completely without destroying my site's layout in the process.

```
font-size: 0px;
line-height: 0;
text-indent: -1000em; 
display: block;
padding-left: 1000px;
```

I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Could we get a sample of the HTML code that you're using? Its a bit difficult to understand what you're trying to do without it.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I go for the all CSS approach:

```
{ display: block;
text-indent: -9999em;
text-transform: uppercase; }
```

For whatever reason, `text-transform: uppercase;` does the trick for IE7. Of course, you'll probably have your own CSS along with that for additional styling (if needed).

Answer (score 2):

Additional to your

```
color: transparent;
```

You can use something like

```
padding-left: 3000px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Regards

Comment: Just to note, `color:transparent` does not work it is an invalid property in color. the fix above will also increase the width of the element significantly

Comment: Since CSS3, 'transparent' has been a legal color in any context. In CSS1, transparent was only legal in background-color, and in CSS2 border-color was added as legal.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can use the propery "content" to change what is contained in the element, personally though I would use javascript to do it.

Just write blank text into the element.

Answer (score 1):

If the button is an input submit button, use the image

```
<input type="image" src="/images/some_image.png" />
```

You can style this with CSS

```
input[type="image"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

If they are links, Dave provided the answer.

Comment: An input of type image should always have an `alt` attribute specified, just as for an ordinary image tag. Given that the OP is concerned about accessibility, you should add it to your example. Something like `alt="Sign me up"` would completely solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make the text disappear in
>   all browsers?

I suppoose you want the altarnative text to disappear if the image is loaded.

For this puprpose you can use this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="images/yourButtongif" HEIGHT="30" WIDTH="100" ALT="Text In Case There Is No Image" />
```

You can apply additional styles if needed, but this minimum will do the job for you.

Comment: I think he is talking about normal button elements, not images.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this might work (I don't have IE7 to test on at the moment, so not 100% sure)

For markup like this:

```
<a href="javascript:return false;" class="button" id="buttonOK"><span
    class="icon">Ok</span></a>
```

Use this css:

```
span.icon {
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    display:block;
    margin-left:-1000;
    width:100px;
}
```

or this might work depending on your requirements for usability/accessibility:

```
span.icon {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what users / programs the labels need to be in the HTML for, but if it's for text browsers and such, maybe you could insert a JavaScript that removes the labels onLoad?

JQuery or Prototype would make that very easy.